# Remove values of certain months of an R Data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following `data.frame` where i want to remove the `values` of certain months replace by an `empty cell` (***Not even NA***)- I tried a few different things but didn't succeed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 Value = runif(1826,1,5)) %>% 
                 mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(Month %in% c(1,2,11,12), Value) <- ""
```

Comment: In R, `NA` *is* what we use as an empty cell. Otherwise it's unclear what you would want—`""` is a string with no length. Aside from that, the syntax is off—I'd recommend the dplyr docs for how to work with its main functions like `mutate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done in this way. note that since you assigned ' ' to a numeric column, **it is no longer a numeric column.**

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 Value = runif(1826,1,5)) 

DF %>%
mutate(Value=ifelse(month(Date)%in% c(1,2,11,12),'',Value))
```

**sample from output;**

```
   Date       Value             
   <date>     <chr>             
 1 2001-03-10 "4.17736928444356"
 2 2005-05-28 "3.43532561417669"
 3 2004-08-10 "2.02042273338884"
 4 2004-11-04 ""                
 5 2005-04-23 "2.43464119918644"
 6 2003-07-01 "1.20879446342587"
 7 2005-08-13 "1.14129407145083"
 8 2002-01-14 ""                
 9 2001-02-19 ""                
10 2002-07-28 "2.69385460391641"
```